# Linking to bootstrap tabs directly without scrolling to anchor

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, scroll, anchor

I have a bootstrap tabs such as this - http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

Everything works fine, but I want to link each tab so I can access it directly

If I link using the anchor (#mytab), the page scroll to that anchor (and the users misses everything about the tab)

Is there a way to create a direct link to a certain tab (via anchor or another method) without scrolling happening?

Comment: Some discussion on a JavaScript solution for this: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2415

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to link directly to a tab and then have the content beneath that tab shown?

Then you need to have some kind of routing in your application. You can use http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes to do that. Inside the callback you should be able to show the correct tab content, prevent scrolling etc.